# Convert maximum values to bit widths

Tags: math, code-challenge, c, test-battery

### Background

The newest version of the C standard, C23, [adds](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2412.pdf) preprocessor macros like `INT_WIDTH`, `ULONG_WIDTH`, and `SIZE_WIDTH` that tell you the bit width of various integer types (here, `int`, `unsigned long`, and `size_t`, respectively).  However, while the majority of us are stuck with pre-C23 compilers/standard libraries, it would still be nice to have these values available to us.

What we do have easy access to is the numerical limits of the integer types, e.g. `INT_MAX`, `ULONG_MAX`, and `SIZE_MAX`.  For unsigned types, these values are guaranteed to be of the form \$2^n - 1\$.  If we could extract the \$n\$ from numbers like this, that would give us the width of every (unsigned) integer type.

### Objective

Your goal is to write a C preprocessor macro `MAX_TO_WIDTH(m)` which converts unsigned `_MAX` values to the corresponding `_WIDTH` value.  More precisely, \$\texttt{MAX_TO_WIDTH}(2^n - 1) = n\$ for all \$n\$ in a "reasonable" range (see below).  For example, we need `MAX_TO_WIDTH(255) == 8`, `MAX_TO_WIDTH(4294967295) == 32`, etc.  Your macro will not be called with other values, so `MAX_TO_WIDTH(10)` can return a garbage value, or even invalid code.

Because macro substitution works by pasting token sequences without evaluating them, fairly succinct macros can have very large expansions.  Therefore, instead of golfing the macro itself, we will be golfing its *output*.

### Rules

1. Your submission should be a C macro definition like

   ```c
   #define MAX_TO_WIDTH(m) ...
   ```

   You may also define and use any helper macros you want to.
2. `MAX_TO_WIDTH(m)` must give the correct result for all \$m = 2^n - 1\$, \$n \in [1, 128]\$.  Most C preprocessors that I know of only handle up to 64-bit integers, but new architectures like [CHERI](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/ctsrd/cheri/) will have 128-bit pointers (and thus `MAX_TO_WIDTH(UINTPTR_MAX) == 128`.  You should verify that your implementation works up to at least 128 bits, for example by translating it to Python.
3. For valid inputs, your macro should produce an integer constant expression suitable for use in a preprocessor condition.  That means things like this must work:

   ```c
   #if MAx_TO_WIDTH(255) == 8
   switch (8) {
       case MAX_TO_WIDTH(255):
           break;
       default:
           assert(0);
   }
   #endif
   ```

   The C preprocessor has slightly different rules than C itself for evaluating expressions (particularly around overflow).
   The result should be correct in either context.
   The test cases attempt to validate this for you.
4. Your macro must properly parenthesize its input and output.  If you're unfamiliar with C, this means that macros like

   ```c
   #define FOO(x) 2 * x + 1
   ```

   Are bad practice because `2 * FOO(1 + 1)` expands to `2 * 2 * 1 + 1 + 1` (a.k.a. 6, not the desired 10).  The macro should instead be written

   ```c
   #define FOO(x) (2 * (x) + 1)
   ```

   The test cases attempt to validate this for you.

### Testing

Add the following code after your macro definition to test it:

```c
/* Check validity in preprocessor conditions */
#if 2 * MAX_TO_WIDTH(1 + 1 + 1) != 4
#error "Expected MAX_TO_WIDTH(3) == 2"
#endif

/* Calculate (1 << n) - 1, without overflow */
#define WIDTH_TO_MAX(n) ((((1ULL << ((n) - 1)) - 1) << 1) + 1)

/* Check that MAX_TO_WIDTH() inverts WIDTH_TO_MAX() */
#define ASSERT_WIDTH(n) _Static_assert(MAX_TO_WIDTH(WIDTH_TO_MAX(n)) == (n), "")

/* Expands to ASSERT_WIDTH(1); ASSERT_WIDTH(2); ...; ASSERT_WIDTH(64); */
#define ASSERT_WIDTH_2(n)  ASSERT_WIDTH(2 * (n) - 1); ASSERT_WIDTH(2 * (n))
#define ASSERT_WIDTH_4(n)  ASSERT_WIDTH_2(2 * (n) - 1); ASSERT_WIDTH_2(2 * (n))
#define ASSERT_WIDTH_8(n)  ASSERT_WIDTH_4(2 * (n) - 1); ASSERT_WIDTH_4(2 * (n))
#define ASSERT_WIDTH_16(n) ASSERT_WIDTH_8(2 * (n) - 1); ASSERT_WIDTH_8(2 * (n))
#define ASSERT_WIDTH_32(n) ASSERT_WIDTH_16(2 * (n) - 1); ASSERT_WIDTH_16(2 * (n))
#define ASSERT_WIDTH_64()  ASSERT_WIDTH_32(1); ASSERT_WIDTH_32(2)
ASSERT_WIDTH_64();

int main(void) {
    int ret[] = {1, 1, 0};
    switch (2) {
        /* Check validity as a constant expression */
        case MAX_TO_WIDTH(3):
            /* Check parenthesization */
            return MAX_TO_WIDTH(3)[ret];
        default:
            return 1;
    }
}
```

The code should compile without errors (warnings are okay), and run successfully (returning 0), without invoking any undefined behaviour.  If you save this code as `golf.c`, you can check it like this:

```
user@host$ clang -fsanitize=undefined golf.c -o golf && ./golf || echo FAIL
```

### Scoring

Your score is the **number of preprocessing tokens** that the test code expands to using your `MAX_TO_WIDTH()` definition.  Lower scores are better.  You can use clang's `-dump-tokens` flag to determine this:

```
user@host$ clang -fsyntax-only -Xclang -dump-tokens golf.c 2>&1 | wc -l
13877
```

This score is insensitive to whitespace, comments, and name length, so there's no incentive to golf the implementation in a way that obfuscates it.

#### Extra credit

If you want, you can calculate the largest \$n\$ for which your \$\texttt{MAX_TO_WIDTH}(2^n - 1)\$ would behave correctly (assuming a hypothetical C implementation with \$n\$-bit integers).  Remember, \$n\$ must be at least 128, but it may be (significantly) higher.  Each \$n\$ defines a "weight class" (so to speak) which includes all submissions with equal or greater \$n\$ values.  For example, with these submissions:

| Submitter | Score | \$n\$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12000 | 128 |
| B | 11000 | 256 |
| C | 13000 | 512 |

We'd have a leaderboard like this:

| Weight class | Winner |
| --- | --- |
| \$n \ge 128\$ | B |
| \$n \ge 256\$ | B |
| \$n \ge 512\$ | C |

Comment: Unsigned overflow isn't undefined, so you should just be able to use `#define WIDTH_TO_MAX(n) ((1ULL << (n)) - 1)`.

Comment: Shifting by the width of the type (or more) is still undefined though

Comment: Fair enough, you'd have to use `#define WIDTH_TO_MAX(n) ((2ULL << (n) - 1) - 1)`.

Comment: Right, that should work.  Do you think it's worth updating the question?  It would change the scores a bit but the only answer so far is mine

Comment: No, I was just commenting because I noticed it while trying (and failing) to answer the question.

Comment: Is the score just 66*atomic_count(your definition)+C?

Comment: @l4m2 Not exactly.  Each occurrence of the parameter `m` in the macro expansion counts for the number of tokens passed to it, which differs between invocations.  The formula is something like `2279 + 66 * non_m_tokens + 3074 * m_tokens`

Comment: I have a score of 10473 for `n=64`... I can't work out how to check larger `n` without a 128-bit preprocessor though.

Answer (score 3):

## n < 160, score <s>11925</s> 11661

```c
#define MAX_TO_WIDTH(x) (~0ull / 31 * ((x) >> 4 & ~0ull / 31 / (~0ull / 31 & 31)) / (~0ull / 32) * 5 + 4 - 12 / (3 + (x) % 31))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZN9a9swEMb/96e4JaxIWZvUjhdK3RTKVtigY9CkdFCKEbIyi3lysOQ0W8m@enay0xfZSSpiBT93z@9OwsePeMbUz/W6m4iZVAK@XfyIp9/j26@fp1/IkgL5d1xmGQxg6EMPiJXOzyGEA3gVGDhpB7hR6ogBRfNH@IDGI/ADGxvim6W9r7LXgx58SgX/BQuWyUSaPyAVzAsxL3IutM4L4LlCXeZKQ2/gdeUMAoQ6/frIrB4K78YQel1RFOjsXC7nghuRuNlDCuMxBB1MQ/LM82wPLONlxowAhJ2dgaK24UN4kCbNSwP5QhSzLH@oWthcWUWzWKQTNBBc/s3VlfUTUhNovVsJd9thXa46skmZcVujeHqsZLQLp6/LXkwml9fTjQGrxBPDjOQx0xqdxOE1WqwOjv@H0OnUjeANMZVoMLnL9WnkCgEK/X6/oY5ClHf0Fge2uwbFfkubm4m2huh2VthiIX437SW4g3fS5oX7eOEbPH9kjY0Se3gnb/CGQYuHJfYAX6I7iKOQNE@MRVoc1ALqtZyR50ll4DeTiixymVB49ACXFQth7u5hDI84L/g7XkVVSOPs8BQQt8m1qz3uTAOzM64NQ5ZY4uxrjdNuP6snF2daNGf49DnqcOesEMqkQsu/zDQwdmGzZaGasDuU76PnRLw/VmbmdJvTr9NW3mr9Hw) [Verify the score!](https://tio.run/##hZRtb9owEMff51PcQGtj1kATMlSVB6namDapU6XBtEpVhTzHLFZTB8UOD@vYV2fnhJUmAWoRo/zv7ndnx@efVIUbRjUMQMcPXKomg17vdHjz6XRTD/hUSA5fr24n45vJjy8fx5/tJQH773kaRdCCtgsNsI00GIAPJ/DC0Cq4neBESEH0CAa/h3cY6IDrGVsb3wztbea9aTXgQ8jZA8xpJAKhVyAkzBI@S2LGlYoTYLFEXcRSQaNl1cUUPIQW6nWRmT0E3vTBt@o8STCyNlzOONM8KHq3CfT74NXQDclTyzI10IilEdUcENbrgSSm4DNYCB3GqYZ4zpNpFC@yErZbltEMFuk2Btg43O/X1ybetnMCyWcj4WwqzNNlS9YhfpNCaQRXj5m0KsLJy7RXo9Hw23gbgFkmI021YBOqFEbaBV6pxGzh@H8GtVpeCO4QlYHCc1HkuqRbFDwUms1mSe34KB@obeKZ6koUc5a2O9PdayL7WX6FhfjDtJ3xAO@iyvOP8fxXeG7HBJZSHOFdvMJrexUepjgC3FkPEDu@XV4xJqlwUPOIVYnsWpaQGh6pkPY8FgGBJwtwGDHh@u4e@vCE/YK/83U3MynsHRYC4ra@ZlTbnSqgpseVpsjiS@x9pbDbzbH6H8Wo4uUevny2FrgzmnCpQ67Eb6pLGDOw2DSRZdgdyvfdZ0fcP5pG@nJfpJu7ra21hReoxSIqf4EzVSup6dKJZbQC53arBunjzMmv3N3N6w1OXPgDCwZOtPkH)

Explanation: The first part masks out the bits corresponding to `2⁴`, `2⁹`, `2¹⁴` etc., then counts just those bits by multiplying by a shifted mask and shifting. This value is multiplied by `5`. Any remaining bits are extracted via `% 31` and these are counted in a similar way to @TavianBarnes' answer by adding `3` and dividing into `12`. In fact this can be done for any number of bits up to `8` using the Fibonacci numbers:

```c
2 - 2 / (1 + (x) % 7)
3 - 6 / (2 + (x) % 15)
4 - 12 / (3 + (x) % 31)
5 - 25 / (5 + (x) % 63)
6 - 48 / (8 + (x) % 127)
7 - 91 / (13 + (x) % 255)
```

For specific values of `n` the score can be reduced by folding the constants.

## n = 128, score <s>10622</s> 10362

```c
#define MAX_TO_WIDTH(x) (0x8421084210842108421084210842108ull * ((x) >> 4 & 0x1084210842108421084210842108421ull) / 0x8000000000000000000000000000000ull * 5 + 4 - 12 / (3 + (x) % 31))
```

Can't try it online but [Verify the score!](https://tio.run/##hZRtb9owEMff51PcQGtjVh4SsgqVB6namDapU6XBtEpVhTzHLFZTB8UOhHV8dnZOWFkSoBYxyt39f3d2fP5JVbBlVMMIdPTIpWoxGAzOx7efzrd1n8@F5PD1@m42vZ39@PJx@tlOCdidtOe5Tuf4lIQhNMA2waMReHAGnfRUPE4oIdDGuF7n5MjR7@EdYpvguKixu/hmcr2FrkPItt2ADwFnj7CkofCFXoOQsIj5Io4YVyqKgUUS7SKSChptqy7m4CK0sE4HmdlD4M0QPKvO4xiVtXG64ExzvxjdJTAcglvDMCTPLcvUQEOWhFRzQNhgAJKYgi9gJXQQJRqiJY/nYbTKSthtdUYzWKTbKLBxON9vbozetnMCyWdjwtlUmKfLlqwD/JaF0giuHjNpVYST/9NeTybjb9OdALPMJppqwWZUKVTaBV6pxGzh@H8BtVpeCO4Qlb7C81TkOqRfNLhoaLVaJeulh@Yjtc1cU12JYk7abmf6B13kMMursBB/nLZ3HuH1qjzvFM97hedcGmEpxQle7xVe163wMMUJ4N57hHjp2eUVY5IKB20usSrKvmUJqeGJCmkvI@ETeLYAhzHGXN8/wBCesV/w19n0M5fC3mEBIG4Xa0a13akCanpcaYosnmLvK4Xdbo7VPxWjipd7@OrFW@AuaMylDrgSv6kuYczAYpNYlmH3aH7ovwTi/tEk1FeHlE4etrE2Fl68Fgup/AXNuVpLTdNmJMM1NO92Vj95WjTzq3p/Y7ujMwf@wIpBM9z@BQ)

## n = 64, score <s>10473</s> 10209

```c
#define MAX_TO_WIDTH(x) (0x1084210842108421ull * ((x) & 0x842108421084210ull) / 0x800000000000000 * 5 + 4 - 12 / (3 + (x) % 31))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZNha9swEIa/@1fcEjakrE1sxwuhbj6UrbBBx2DJ2KAUI2RlFvPkYCmpt5Lfnp3srK3sJBWxgu/ufe6V8PFznjP1c7frp2IplYDPVz@SxZfk@6cPi4@kokD8KvCnUfhsW@c5DIDY7BvwKzfpY5bCyMZ9Z6HkHbyFCM4hCLGAjPHNMl7DOKB0NxrA@0zwX7BhuUyl@QNSwaoUq7LgQuuiBF4ojMtCaRiMvL5cQohQx3CAzPqh8GoGkdcXZYnK3nW1EtyI1K0eU5jNIOxhGZKXnmc9sJyvc2YEIOzyEhS1hs/gXpqsWBsoNqJc5sV9bWF/ZzXNYpFOUEBwBd9ubqyekIZAm92GcLcOm3b1kU3GjGuN4umxk9EunD5vezWfX39d7AXYJZkbZiRPmNaoJA6vZbE@OP6fQa/XGMEbYirVYAqXG9DYDYQYGA6HregkwvARb0lo3bUo9gva30x8MEUPs6IOC/HHaU/JI7xplxed4kUv8IKJFbZanOBNX@CNww4PW5wAPmWPECcRaZ8Ym3Q4GAup11HGnieVgd9MKrIpZErhwQNcNlgKc3sHM3jAecGfv43rlMbZ4Rkgbl9rV3fcmQZmZ1wbhixR4exrjdNuP6v/Ks60aM/wxWPW4a5YKZTJhJZ/mWlh7EKz61K1YbcYvosfC/H@2Do3F4eUQVO29ba7fw) [Verify the score!](https://tio.run/##hZR/b9owEIb/z6e4gdbGrIEkZAgVqFStTJvUqdLotEpVhbzELFZTB8UOhHV8dnZOWGkSoBYxyv147rXj8y8qw41PFVyAih@ZkG0fhsPT8c3n000zYDMuGHy7vJve3kx/fr26/WJmBEw7c@y@576a0iiCFpjaewJ2Vnba6CXQ0Xa7NDDlI3wADyxwXAwwu/imGe@h6xCy6bTgU8j8R1jQiAdcrYALmCdsnsQ@kzJOwI8F2nksJLQ6RpPPwEVoSbCDzPwh8G4EntFkSYKZjXE2Z75iQTm6S2A0AreBYUieGYbWQCM/jahigLDhEATRgs9gyVUYpwriBUtmUbzMJWz3LKdpLNJNTDBxOD@ur3W@aRYEUszahLNWWJTLl6xC/CglaQRXj5WULMPJ67KXk8n4@@02AatMJ4oq7k@plJhplngVifnC8f8MGo1CCO4QFYHEg1HmOmRQNrhoaLfbFWvPQ/MBbVNXq6tQ9Ana7sxgr4vsZ3k1FuIP03bOA7x@necd43lv8JyeTqyUOMLrv8HrujUeljgC3HkPEHueWV0xFqlx0OYSo5Y5MAwuFDxRLsxFzAMCzwbg0MaEqfsHGMEz9gv@7PUgd0nsHT8ExG1j9ai3O5VAdY9LRZHFMux9KbHb9bH6n@VTyao9fP7iLXHnNGFChUzyP1RVMHqg2DQRVdg9mh8GL4G4fzSN1Pm@TKcIWxtrA29Qw4@o@A3WTK6EopkVi2gF1t3WGqRPc6u4c3dXr3tx4sBfWPpgRZt/)

Edit: Saved a bunch from all the scores by removing <s>a</s> two sets of unnecessary parentheses (in some cases I had to switch a right shift to a divide by a power of `2`).

Answer (score 2):

## Score: <s>13877</s> 13613, \$n = 2040\$.

*-264 thanks to l4m2*

```c
#define CHUNK(m, mask) (m) / ((m) % mask + 1) / mask % mask
#define INTERP(m) 7 - 86 / ((m) % 255 + 12)
#define MAX_TO_WIDTH(m) (CHUNK(m, 255) * 8 + INTERP(m))
```

---

This idea is due to Hallvard B. Furuseth on a [comp.lang.c post](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.c/c/NfedEFBFJ0k/m/9HAqis6IDqcJ) in 2003.  It uses this helper function

```c
#define CHUNK(m, mask) (m) / ((m) % mask + 1) / mask % mask
```

Which is used to make a repeating sequence like this:

$$
\begin{aligned}
a_{i,j} & = \texttt{CHUNK}(2^i - 1, 2^j - 1) \\
a_{0,j}, a_{1,j}, a_{2,j}, \ldots & = \underbrace{0, \ldots, 0}_{\text{$j$ times}}, \underbrace{1, \ldots, 1}_{\text{$j$ times}}, \cdots, \underbrace{2^j-2, \ldots, 2^j - 2}_{\text{$j$ times}}, 0, \ldots
\end{aligned}
$$

You can play around with it in Python to see:

```python
>>> def CHUNK(m, mask):
...     return (m) // ((m) % mask + 1) // mask % mask
... 
>>> def a(i, j):
...     return CHUNK(2**i - 1, 2**j - 1)
... 
>>> [a(i, 2) for n in range(10)]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1]
>>> [a(i, 3) for n in range(10)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
>>> [a(i, 4) for n in range(10)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
>>> [a(n, 5) for n in range(5 * (2**5 - 1))] == \
... [i for i in range(2**5 - 1) for j in range(5)]
True
```

This sequence has \$j \, (2^j - 1)\$ values before it wraps, meaning

$$
\texttt{CHUNK}(2^i - 1, 2^j - 1) = \lfloor i/j \rfloor \quad \text{for all $i < j \, (2^j - 1)$.}
$$

This is almost enough—what we want is \$j \, \lfloor i/j \rfloor + (i \bmod j) = i\$.  We can get \$(i \bmod j)\$ in various ways.  For now, let's fix \$j = 8\$.  We know that \$2^i \pmod {2^8 - 1}\$ will have period 8:

```python
>>> [(2**i - 1) % 255 for i in range(16)]
[0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127]
```

And we can brute force a linear interpolation of these that maps them to `[0, 1, 2, ...]`:

```python
>>> [(7 - 86 // ((2**i - 1) % 255 + 12)) for i in range(16)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

---

The [original post](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.c/c/NfedEFBFJ0k/m/9HAqis6IDqcJ) is more like this:

```c
#define CHUNK(m, mask) (m) / ((m) % mask + 1) / mask % mask
#define INTERP(m) 4 - 12 / ((m) % 31 + 3)
#define MAX_TO_WIDTH(m) \
    (CHUNK(m, 0x3fffffffL) * 30 + CHUNK((m) % 0x3fffffff, 31) * 5 + INTERP(m))
```

Which would have score: 21477, \$n = 30 \cdot (2^{30} - 1) = 32212254690\$.

Comment: Brackets besides `INTERP(m)` is unnecessary

Comment: So is the `CHUNK` one